# Toggle "on/off" with small resistance change

Tags: transistors, schematics, photoresistor

I'm trying to make a small model car stop when it crosses a black line on the ground. My idea is to use a photresistor + some magic to do the trick. I'm here for the magic part...

The resistor I have at hand changes its resistance between 5 and 8 kiloohms between "bright" and "dark" underground. I also have some BD137 transistors. The car is powered by a 9V battery pack and the motor draws 100 mA.

What is the easiest possible circuit to completely stop the motor at "high" resistance and make it run at full speed at "low" resistance?

Comment: Using a photoresistor you're going to have to rely on a whole lot of magic (or a snail like pace - or an unusually thick black line). Photoresistors are extremely slow, and can easily take a full second to react to a drop in brightness. It would be much more practical (i.e. doable) to use a phototransistor or photodiode instead.

Answer (score 1):

5 K to 8 K is not much of a change, but a single comparator stage driving a switching transistor should be able to do what you want.  With a dual comparator one half does the compare work and the other half drives back to the input to latch the comparator against further detections until the circuit is reset.  How do you plan to reset the detector for another run?

Comment: "single comparator stage driving a switching transistor" if I knew exactly what that means, I'd probably figured it out by myself :)

Answer (score 1):

You could form a voltage divider (LDR1+R1) that will turn on your transistor (and hence, your motor) when the photoresistor is illuminated and turn it off otherwise. When illuminated, LDR1 supplies base current to Q1, which is amplified and fed to the base of Q2, allowing it to turn on fully. When it's too dark, the resistance of LDR1 rises, and the voltage at the base of Q1 drops below 1.2 V, which is necessary for Q1Q2 to operate. The transistors turn off, and the motor stops. But really, the difference between the light and dark resistance is too small, this schematic won't function reliably when the battery voltage drops below about 7.5 V.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fskcaO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: This seems to do the trick, I'll have a look at the supply voltage issue and the photoresistor's latency.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible circuit. When the LDR resistance rises above the value of R3 the output MOSFET latches off via D2 and SW1 resets it, (or possibly you could shine a bright enough light on LDR1 to reduce the resistance to a few hundred ohms and lose the switch).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXUYwb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: how is this the "easiest possible circuit"?

Comment: @Jasper If you don't care if it works reliably or not I can make it much simpler. Just 2 parts- the MOSFET and one resistor (select it to sortof work), plus the LDR, and hope the MOSFET will avalanche  safely when the motor turns off (and no latching function).

Comment: @AnalogKid Yup, almost the same as your concept but with a single comparator (op-amp). +1 for you.